# Ipython is failing with error "'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed"

Tags: ipython, jupyter

Jupyter notebook is running on the localhost, but while I am trying to run python script in cell it is giving following error-

```
[I 22:39:47.748 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/tiwari/Practice/note_book
[I 22:39:47.748 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 22:39:47.748 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8999/
[I 22:39:47.748 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 22:39:50.862 NotebookApp] Session not found: session_id=u'9c6cd3bd-9501-4f5c-9bc0-fa374f624012'
[W 22:39:50.864 NotebookApp] 404 DELETE /api/sessions/9c6cd3bd-9501-4f5c-9bc0-fa374f624012 (127.0.0.1) 4.25ms referer=http://localhost:8999/notebooks/packages/DataStructure/test_stack.ipynb
[I 22:39:50.895 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0129ae3f-cb4f-4b1b-ac62-b3e4b68b4a3a
/usr/bin/python: cannot import name Empty; 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
[I 22:39:53.897 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
/usr/bin/python: cannot import name Empty; 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
[I 22:39:56.900 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
/usr/bin/python: cannot import name Empty; 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
[I 22:39:59.907 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
/usr/bin/python: cannot import name Empty; 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
[W 22:40:00.933 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 0129ae3f-cb4f-4b1b-ac62-b3e4b68b4a3a
[I 22:40:02.911 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 0129ae3f-cb4f-4b1b-ac62-b3e4b68b4a3a restarted
/usr/bin/python: cannot import name Empty; 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
[W 22:40:05.916 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 22:40:05.916 NotebookApp] Kernel 0129ae3f-cb4f-4b1b-ac62-b3e4b68b4a3a died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 0129ae3f-cb4f-4b1b-ac62-b3e4b68b4a3a restarted failed!
[W 22:40:05.927 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 22:40:05.927 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/1de806ab-9800-47a2-bd00-19b0c501d52a (127.0.0.1) 1.84ms referer=http://localhost:8999/notebooks/packages/DataStructure/test_stack.ipynb
```

Comment: I already deleted the virtualEnv and recreated with same libraries, that won't resolve the issue.

Comment: `cannot import name Empty` looks like the relevant bit. Do you have a file called `queue.py` or `Queue.py` in the working directory?

Comment: Yes @ThomasK, I have a package Queue and Queue.py inside it

Comment: I would guess that is clashing with the standard library [queue module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). Try calling your package something else.